# Detect whether a PG database schema (the data dictionary) changed

Tags: postgresql

Is there a quick way to detect whether a PostgreSQL database schema changed? (Is there an internal sequence or sth which gets incremented when PG schema operation like `ALTER TABLE` run)? I would like to cache data based on schema queries and need an invalidation marker.

One approach is to run the schema-reflection queries (against pg_class, pg_attribute and all the others) and produce a hash over them, but I wonder whether there may be a simpler way to accomplish the same. It doesn't need to be exact, just signal that it is time to flush the cache and reload the schema in the application layer.

To clarify: This is NOT about schema migration or getting schema diffs. It is just about a cache invalidation marker. That is a simple flag: "did the schema change at all since marker X". (Also I'm not talking about a schema namespace, but about the data dictionary aka the schema ([database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema)). That is, changes to the structure of the database.)

Or in other words: Is there a PG version of the SQLite3 `PRAGMA schema_version`.

Comment: A sequence getting incremented does not imply a *schema change*. Just to be clear. It's a database object which holds a current value and has an ability to generate another value. I think you need to define *schema change* is adding an index a schema change? You referring to any operation within the schema?

Comment: I'm asking about changes to the _schema_, not about changes to the contents of a database. I.e. ALTER TABLE, DROP TABLE, ADD COLUMN, etc, all operations which alter the structure of the database. Presumably CREATE INDEX and such are in the same category.

Comment: @hhh that's what I thought but this threw me off, could you explain it: *sequence that gets incremented*

Comment: Updated the question. No, I don't care if arbitrary sequences are incremented, I wonder whether there is some internal sequence (pg_whatever) that gets incremented on schema changes.

Comment: you can save pg_class then and compare changes periodically

Comment: This sounds like my 'One approach is to run the schema-reflection queries and produce a hash over them'? Which I guess might be OK. Just hashing pg_class is not enough, right? To detect column changes I would have to run the full thing?

Comment: column changes would be in pg_attribute

Comment: Yes, I know. So my question stands: To detect any change to the schema, do I have to rerun all schema reflection queries or is there some other update marker I can check.

Comment: if there would be, there would not be all those flyways and squitches and other tools. in other words - nothing comes to my mind :)

Comment: I just want a change marker for a cache, no diffing or migration at all

Answer (score 4):

## Using an `EVENT TRIGGER`

An [`EVENT TRIGGER` on `ddl_command_end` can be created](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-event-triggers.html) that gets a row with a `schema`

> **schema** Name of the schema the object belonged in, if any; otherwise NULL. No quoting is applied.

Here is a [list of everything `ddl_command_end` currently fires on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-trigger-matrix.html)

See the [Chapter on Event Triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-triggers.html) in the docs for more info.

Comment: This is great! Doesn't solve my needs as I don't want to touch / alter the database, but very close to what I want.

Comment: @hnh you don't want to touch or alter the database through the features that do just what you want. You don't want to work outside the database, through the features that do just what you want. You know there is no magical bool value that does what you want in the way you want. What are you bothering for?

Comment: "You know there is no magical bool value that does what you want in the way you want". No, I don't know. Hence my question?! It may very well be the outcome. Maybe someone else has another idea.

Answer (score -1):

## Using `pg_dump`

I think the easy (potentially only) way to do this is to cache a schema diff using `pg_dump`

```
pg_dump --schema-only --schema myschema
```

And then detect whether or not the schema has changed with the dump. You may want to filter out sequences. No PostgreSQL solution for logical replication works with DDL.

Comment: From within a shell script this would probably the easiest way. But it is way faster to just query pg_class etc (the stuff which makes up the things you reflect on) and produce a hash over them, this approach is even worse. I was looking for a _faster_ way :-) Maybe my question isn't clear enough :-)

Comment: There is no "simple bool" you've got to make one. A schema is a conceptual container and nothing more. Your question should be a lot clearer. Why is this not fast enough? Why do you think reinventing something that enumerates over the entire schema would be faster? No one knows what you say when you mean *schema*. We know what `pg_dump` means by it.

Comment: > Your question should be a lot clearer.

It looks pretty clear to me, but I'm happy to incorporate suggestions (well, anyone can edit the question :-). I would appreciate if you would find the time to improve my question.

> Why is this not fast enough?

I show the available tables/cols in a web interface, so I'd like to check for changes in every single HTTP request. 'Not fast enough' was not the Q, my Q was whether there is a faster way but to requery all.

> No one knows what you say when you mean *schema*.

Really? Is there a different meaning for schema?

Comment: @hnh yes, you've defined schema now to exclude internal sequences, but the pg_dump for `--schema`, because it's defined as non-data actually includes internal sequences. When we say schema, we don't typically include roles, but my other answer using `ddl_command_end` includes `GRANT` and `REVOKE`. Anyway, yes "schema" is a complex term when you're talking about this.

Comment: I've tried to clarify what I mean by schema in the question, also via the Wikipedia link. I don't care about a few false positives produced by GRANT/REVOKE or others, I can still run the hash-check at that time instead of every time. I just don't want the marker to move by regular CRUD operations in the database. The EVENT TRIGGER looks great, but I don't want to touch the actual database and install TRIGGERs just for that. So far it looks like there is no easier way to poll for changes.